# PHP Search for a string in remote webpage

Tags: php

I am trying to write a script with PHP where it'll open up a text file ./urls.txt and check each domain for a specific word. I am really new to PHP.

Example: 
Look for the word "Hello" in the following domains.
List:
Domain1.LTD
Domain2.LTD
Domain3.LTD

and just simply print out domain name + valid/invalid.

```
<?PHP
$link = "http://yahoo.com"; //not sure how to loop to read each line from a file.
$linkcontents = file_get_contents($link);

$needle = "Hello";
if (strpos($linkcontents, $needle) == false) {
echo "Valid";
} else {
echo "Invalid";
}
?>
```

Comment: Use [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) then [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
$arrayOfLinks = array(
    "http://example.com/file.txt",
    "https://www.example-site-2.com/files/file.txt"
    );
    
    $needle = "Hello";
    
    foreach($arrayOfLinks as $link){ // loop through the array
    
        $linkcontents = file_get_contents($link);
    
        if (stripos($linkcontents , $needle) !== false) { // stripos is case-insensitive search
    // the needle exists in $linkcontents
    // !== false instead of != false since stripos can return 0 meaning the needle is the first word of the contents
        echo "Valid";
        } else {
    // the word does not exist in the given text
        echo "Invalid";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all use **[CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php)** in favor of **file_get_contents()** because of security.

This would be a correct `strpos` example:

```
//your previous code
if (strpos($linkcontents, $needle) !== false) { // see the !==
echo "Valid"; //Needle found
} else {
echo "Invalid"; //Needle not found
}
```

For more complex crawling you could use some `regexp` instead of `strpos`.

Comment: How does this loop through the list of domain in a file? And curl is not more or less secure then fgc...

Comment: @LozCheroneツ thanks for the reminder. Do you know which is better `file()` or `CURL`?

Comment: there two different things.. file is not more or less better then curl ;p